# CakePHP and Flex - Can they integrate and if so is it ugly or nice?

Tags: php, apache-flex, cakephp, frameworks

I'm looking at a new project and we are wanting to use Flex (to provide the easy integration with AIR and provide a desktop app for our project). How easy does CakePHP play with Flex or is there a better PHP framework to use with Flex, or should we use none?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that is PHP based can benefit from [AMFPHP](http://www.amfphp.org/) to that matter.

There's a project in [Cakeforge](https://cakeforge.org/projects/cakeamfphp/) that tries to create that bridge, although I think it's a bit outdated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Rails + Flex guy, but IIRC, CakePHP is very similar to Rails.  Assuming that's true, the MVC architecture works quite well with a Flex front end.

Really the only difference between a Flex app and a regular HTML app is returning XML for Flex to interpret instead of HTML for the browser to interpret.  From that perspective, pairing Flex with any MVC framework is a good idea over going with flat PHP.